# Node.js Backend API with Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I was just curious if it is worth while to use webpack to bundle a Node.js backend API or if others out there are doing this in practice.  I am currently developing a few Node.js APIs and wondered if others felt that this was worth while or if just using straight up Node.js without webpack or babel was the better way to go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've yet to see the benefit of using something like webpack for the backend. This is running in your server so bundling and concatenation etc make little sense.

Transpilation, on the other hand, is a great thing to have for your javascript code. As long as you're compiling from something that doesn't try to completely mutate javascript (I'm looking at you coffeescript). So feel free to use Babel or Typescript for your backend.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was feeling kind of the same.  It seems to me that webpack is great for frontend react apps that will communicated with a backend API but for the backend I didn't see the value.  I definitely agree that transpilation is valuable expecially since node doesn't fully support all of the ES6 features I like to use.  :) . Thanks again.

Comment: to push this further from what i've seen in my company where a two nodejs project are built with webpack, there is a little bit of config "hacking" to ensure webpack doesn't break the app. Like it isn't meant to be used that way?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on node project that has been built by webpack/babel because await and several things from ES7 were used.

For example `await` is compiled like `while(true)` till the query receive the result. I don't think that is optimal.

Node.js supports ES6 and it is enough to use it clear.